# Clickonce and app.config

Tags: installation, clickonce, app-config

I am installing a WPF Application using the ClickOnce deployment. There are certain settings in the app.config that need to be changed after the Application is installed. Although the app.config exists in the deployment folder as assemblyname.exe.config.deploy , after installing the application I can't seem to find it on the client machine so that I can change the settings.

Where do I look for it, any pointers?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The application configuration is located in here (replace <username> by the username, XP users look in "Document and Settings"):

C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0

It's located in one of those semi-cryptic subfolders, but I'm sure you'll get it :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) (a VS extension). With this you can create a transformation for your app.config file based on your build configuration (i.e debug/release). Then when you publish with ClickOnce your app.config file (or any other XML file for that matter) will be transformed into the ClickOnce package which gets published. You can find a sample at https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/tree/master/SlowCheetah.Samples/Wpf.Transform.

Comment: The orignal github repo has been deprecated and links you to https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

as per [How to get folder path for ClickOnce application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359026/how-to-get-folder-path-for-clickonce-application), you can get the folder of a running task by right-clicking it in the Task Manager (or for earlier versions of windows in Process Explorer from www.SysInternals.com)

[image]