# Local installed location of the clickonce application

Tags: c#, clickonce

I need to know where the clickonce application got installed. Is there a way to find this through C#?

Comment: What would you do with such information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, the physical files end up in this directory: C:\Documents and Settings\userprofile\Local Settings\Apps in Win XP and C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Apps for Windows 7.

You can also read more about this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359026/how-to-get-folder-path-for-clickonce-application).

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx) and then check the [`Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx) property of the result. This will return the path of the currently executing assembly.