# WPF .NET Clickonce deployment install location

Tags: .net, clickonce

I'm trying to find the location where a clickonce deployment is installed on a local machine.  I find a program reference in the start menu, but not the actual exe file.  What I'm really trying to find is the config file so that I can debug some strangeness that one of the users is experiencing.  I feel like if I can find the config file and copy it into the same location on my development machine I can verify what is happening.

Note that this is a desktop WPF application, not a browser based application.

Answer (score 3):

It makes a new folder for each version. The name of that folder is randomly generated so nobody can tell you where it is. I wish I was joking. It's installed to the user profile.

You will find them in this folder:

```
\Users\$UserName\AppData\Local\Apps\
```

The best way to be sure is to run the application and then trace the running executable to it's current location. This could change the next time it is run because when C2R updates it makes a new folder for the new version.

This was answered before in this Q: [How to get folder path for ClickOnce application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359026/how-to-get-folder-path-for-clickonce-application)

Here is the best answer from that thread:

> To find the folder location, you can just run the app, open the task
>   manager (CTRL-SHIFT-ESC), select the app and right-click|Open file
>   location.