# Replacement for obsolete Assembly.CodeBase in .NET 6 / .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, vsto, compatibility, .net-6.0

We deploy a helper-executable along with our VSTO / Outlook AddIn via ClickOnce.

In the AddIn, we have a button which starts this helper-executable in a new process (it's needed because the AddIn runs as 32-bit / coupled with Outlook-bitness).

Until now I managed it by using `Assembly.CodeBase` to get the path of the installed VSTO dll, where I also can find the helper-executable.

I can not use `Assembly.Location` since this points to another cryptic cache-path where I can only find the current dll, not my installed bunch of dlls with helper-executable.

Now the problem: in .NET core / .NET 6, `Assembly.CodeBase` is obsolete, so how can I find my helper-executable in my outlook add-in?

Any other ideas, how to achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try compiling in Net and then target Core/Net 6.  Then you may need to download the runtime library for Core 6.0 : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0?force_isolation=true

Comment: By the way, since I found out that Outlook AddIns are no longer supported for .net core /.net 6, this question is more ore less useless ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.basedirectory?view=net-6.0) property which returns the base directory that the assembly resolver uses to probe for assemblies. See [How to get folder path for ClickOnce application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359026/how-to-get-folder-path-for-clickonce-application#:%7E:text=ClickOnce%20applications%20DO%20reside%20in,of%20C%3A%5CDocuments%20%26%20Settings.) for other alternatives.

Comment: Thanks. The second link pointed me to "System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory", which also works on .NET 6.
You could edit your post, then I'll accept as answer :)

Comment: Cool! I've updated the post.